# erase file by batches

Tags: linux, find, erase

Need to erase 150K files from a folder, and I want to erase them by batches

what would be the best way ?

for instance delete the first 1000 results of

```
find . -time +600 -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: What is the motivation for doing them in batches?

Comment: Are their names predictable? I mean, do they contain sequence numbers or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Your command assumes that there are no subdirs, so that's what I'll assume.
This is in a bash

```
find . -print > /tmp/gaga

for i in `head -n 1000 /tmp/gaga`
do
rm -f $i
done
```

Then repeat until no more files.